# My oven insulation is burning when I bake

Tags: insulation, oven

My oven burns every time I bake. The insulation always seems to light up when I use it.

Also, some rats infested it a while back and really caused damage but they all died.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My understanding of oven insulation infestation is that it pretty much kills the oven; the only way to fix it would be to replace the insulation, and that is more expensive than a new oven.

Comment: Definitely time to stop using the oven so you don't accidentally start a fire in the whole house. It might not even be safe to use the cook top (assuming it's a one piece unit), as whatever caused the damage to the oven that's allowing the insulation to ignite could have impacted the wiring in the cook top, too.

Comment: Dead rat, rat droppings, rats chewed insulation, shiny bobbles collected by rats and nested in the oven.   Rats, i think i think you need a new oven.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

you probably have some loose /corroded connections that are arcing and burning some insulation. The rats could have gnawed at some of the wire insulation causing arcing.

You need to get this looked at. Very little you could do safely. It is dangerous.